# Flutter Laravel Push Notification without using any third party like(firebase,onesignal..etc)

Tags: flutter, laravel-8, laravel-api

I'm making a mobile app that has push notification, from frontend I'm using flutter and backend I'm using laravel api and Postgres12 as database. I need to do a push notification where laravel will notify flutter of new notification whenever the database is updated. How to make a a reliable connection between flutter and laravel and that the push notification will work. Please help I have try searching for answers everywhere but I couldn't find the one that can help me solve the problem.

Comment: I really didn't understand your question. commenting what I did understand. are you trying to  make your own push notification server.  You need to consider firebase  like services.

Comment: yes own push notification from laravel

Comment: This is almost impossible. Since your app will finally come to the background, it cannot maintain a long connection to the server using whatever technologies. You should integrate both your client & service to products like APN or Firebase push notification to achieve this, which offer push notification capability in the OS level.

Comment: I agree with @mahi. But You  can use firebase messaging pakage to receive push notifications on flutter side. To send notifications from Bank-end(laravel) you need to call firebase api from your server.

Comment: I cannot used firebase , thats why im in really in trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better I understand, you can not make your own push notification server. What you can do is use the available services like firebase and **can't doesn't mean impossible.**

read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850054/create-my-own-push-notification-service-without-fcm-pusher)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Awesome Notification Package](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications). This might be helpful for you!

Comment: thanks but my problem is connecting flutter and laravel